# Regex get all before first occurrence of character

Tags: regex

I know it's been asked many many times. I tried my best but the result wasn't perfect.

Regex

```
/(\(\s*["[^']*]*)(.*\/logo\.png.*?)(["[^']*]*\s*\))/gmi
```

Regex101 Link: https://regex101.com/r/0f8Q08/1

It should capture all separately.

```
(../asdasd/dasdas/logo.png) 
(../asdasd/dasdas/logo.png) 
( '../logo.png' )
```

Right now it's capturing as a whole.

```
(../asdasd/dasdas/logo.png) (../asdasd/dasdas/logo.png) ( '../logo.png' )
```

What I need is, the regex to stop after the first closing bracket ) match.

[image: wrong text capture]

Comment: wrong capture as seen in the screenshot

Comment: do you need regex? if you are looking for first occurrence of a character most languages have a indexOf

Comment: Need regex because mine isn't perfect

Comment: Like this? `(\(\s*["[^']*]*)([^()]*\/logo\.png[^()]*)(["[^']*]*\s*\))` https://regex101.com/r/D11pXu/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use regex you can make the change from `.*` to `[^)]` so you stay between parenthesis

```
(\(\s*["[^']*]*)([^)]*\/logo\.png.*?)(["[^']*]*\s*\))
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0f8Q08/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(\(\s*(["']?))([^"')]*\/logo\.png[^"')]*)(\2\s*\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YX0nRI/1).

*Details*

- `(\(\s*(["']?))` - Group 1: `(`, any zero or more whitespaces, and then Group 2 capturing either a `'` or a `"` optionally
- `([^"')]*\/logo\.png[^"')]*)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than `"`, `'` and `)`, then a `/logo.png` string, and then again any zero or more chars other than `"`, `'` and `)`
- `(\2\s*\))` - Group 4: the same value as in Group 2, zero or more whitespaces, and a `)` char.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your pattern is that the `.*` matches too much. After the opening parenthesis, you should exclude matching the `(` and `)` to overmatch the separate parts.

You don't need all those capture groups if you want to match the parts with parenthesis as a whole.

You can use 1 capture group, where the group would be a backreference matching the same optional closing quote.

```php
\(\s*(["']?)[^()'"]*\/logo\.png[^()'"]*\1\s*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rsV1oy/1)

If you also want the matches without the matching quotes:

```
\(\s*["']?[^()'"]*\/logo\.png[^()'"]*["']?\s*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HftZ01/1)